# Is it possible to write code in c# to create a table in a Word document when it´s open by me?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Is it possible to write code in c# to create a table in a Word document which it´s already open by me? I don't want to close it before to edit it.

The code I use now is

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; 

private void TestOpenWordDoc
{
 Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application(); 
 object objMissing = Type.Missing;
 Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fullFilePath,
    ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
    ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
    ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
    ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing); 
}
```

But the document must be closed in order to use it.

Comment: Yes, if you talk to Word. You can use the Word COM objects to talk to the open instance of Word and manipulate the document.

Comment: I've finally managed to put it together - see my (corrected) answer.

Comment: Has my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Getting an open document in Word in the VBA world is well-known: GetObject with the application class as a string will pick up the running instance registered in the ROT. Or passing it a document name will pick up that document window, or open the document if it's not already open. The method wraps up the Windows APIs for the VBA user.

In the .NET world this isn't quite so simple, but the information in this blog article from Andrew Whitechapel does a good job of summarizing the possibilities: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/11/30/launching-office-apps-programmatically/

The one I generally use combines `GetProcessesByName` with `Marshal.GetActiveObject`, which is a very similar approach to the VBA method.

For example:

```
    Word.Application wdApp = null; //class level member

  private void btnRunningWordTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getWordInstance();
        Word.Document doc = wdApp.ActiveDocument;
        //Debug.Print(wdApp.ActiveDocument.FullName);
        Word.Table tbl = null;
        Word.Range rng = doc.Content;
        if (doc.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            tbl = doc.Tables[1];
        }
        else
        {
            //Make sure to not replace existing content - put the table at the end
            rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
            tbl = doc.Tables.Add(rng, 3, 3, Word.WdDefaultTableBehavior.wdWord8TableBehavior, ref missing);
        }
        if (tbl != null)
        {
            Debug.Print(tbl.Rows.Count.ToString());
        }
    }

    internal void getWordInstance()
    {
        try
        {
            if (wdApp == null)
            {
                Process[] wdPcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("WinWord");
                int nrWordInstances = wdPcs.Length - 1;
                if (nrWordInstances >= 0)
                {
                    //Picks up other running instance, not new one
                    wdApp = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
                }
                else
                    wdApp = new Word.Application();
            }
            wdApp.Visible = true;
            wdApp.Activate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since it opens a new word instance, this will result in a prompt from word where it says the file is already locked by the user and the user should select one of the three options: "open a readonly copy", "make a copy of the file and merge the changes once the file is available", "notify when the file is available". At least it is what is does on Office 2017 and .net 4.7.2.

Comment: @JohanLang <thunk> Yes, I lost track of what the problem is - my bad. I'm currently on a mobile device, but will fix my suggestion when I'm at a "real" machine in a few hours. Sorry about that!

Comment: No problem at all, it happens :) Cannot wait to see the solution to satiate my own curiosity as well ;)